# Php getting values from a shell script

Tags: php, shell, scripting, sh

I have an issue that I need to solve for a company.

From the command line I need to execute the php file named testScript.php
Code is below.

```
<?php
 $databaseName = shell_exec('enterDatabaseName.sh');
 echo $databaseName;
 ?>
```

I want to run the shell script file called enterDatabaseName.sh which prompts the to enter a name of a database. I then need that value that the user entered to be stored in the $databaseName variable in php.
The code below is what I have attempted so far for my shell script.  For some reason when I attempt to echo the $databaseName variable in php it does not work. Any ideas ?

```
#! /bin/bash
echo "Enter database name:"
read databaseName
return $databaseName
```

Answer (score 0):

1. you can't use `return` outside a function. Use `echo` instead
2. Remove the first `echo` in your script and put the text inside your `read`. because every text in the `echo` statement will go to your `shell_exec`  result in PHP.

result:

```
#! /bin/bash
read -p "Enter database name: " databaseName
echo $databaseName
```